# Из-за чего вылетает ошибка initializationError при сборке проекта в gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, jar

Пытаюсь собрать проект в jar файл грэдлом. Там всего 1 класс. Его код:

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {

    private static String host=null;
    private static String login=null;
    private static String password=null;
    private static FirefoxDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void openBrowser(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

    {

        if(args.length >= 3) {
            Test testObject= new Test();
            testObject.openBrowser();
            testObject.test(args[0], args[1],args[2]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No data transmitted");
        }
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test(String host, String login,String password){

        System.out.println("Starting test " + new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
        driver.get(host);
        driver.findElement(By.name("identity")).sendKeys(login);
        driver.findElement(By.name("credential")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
        System.out.println("Ending test " + new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
    }
}
```

Код из файла .build:

```
group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'



sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.53.0'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:2.53.0'
}
```

Сам класс компилируется и отрабатывает,но когда я даю команду gradle build  в консоли, он выдает следующее:

```
optimumsmini73:testHourlies igor$ gradle build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
4 warnings
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test

Test > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.Exception

1 test completed, 1 failed
:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/igor/IdeaProjects/testHourlies/build/reports/tests/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.721 secs
```

В чем может быть проблема?На что мне обратить внимание?

Comment: `There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/igor/IdeaProjects/testHourlies/build/reports/tests/index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод с аннотацией `@Test` не должен содержать параметров. Уберите ее.

Comment: если убрать эту аннотацию это ни на что не повлияет?

Comment: Нет не повлияет. Я бы еще @BeforeClass убрал для того чтобы совсем надежно стало.

Comment: уберу.скажите а для чего эти аннотации нужны?я знаю,что обычно аннотации помогают ide лучше "понять" что за метод идет дальше. а в данном случае для чего эти @Test и @AfterClass?

Comment: Аннотации не для IDE. В разных случаях они решают разные цели. Давайте посмотрим на наш случай. Вы собираете проект с помощью gradle. Жизненный цикл такой сборки выглядит так: компиляция -> тестирjвание -> jar. На шаге тестирования junit проходит во вашим классам и ищет методы с аннотацией @Test. Далее пытается их выполнить уже по своему сценарию. А там уже начинанют работать BeforeClass и AfterClass. Хорошо прочитать https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/understaning-junit-method-order-execution/

Comment: стало намного понятнее.проект собрался,но при запуске через консоль (команда java -jar test-Hour.jar) пишет,что java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver
я так понимаю,он не может найти класс библиотеки селениума?разве грэдл не прописывает пути и зависимости в jar -файл?

Comment: По умолчанию - нет. Можно взять что-нибудь из https://discuss.gradle.org/t/package-dependencies-with-jar/10202/2

Comment: немного странное обсуждение(я так и не понял,как автор решил эту проблему). попробовал оба способа,но когда я пытаюсь как-то добавить в .build файл то,что они советуют не подходит в овтет вижу,что та или иная конфигурация cannot be applied(to Groovylang closure)

Comment: ... Или запускть java  с опцией -Djava.library.path=%там_где_либы_лежат%

Comment: а у gradle нет каких-то скриптов, или плагина, который при сборки джарника кладет в него необходимые либо из dependencies?

Comment: Вариант https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar

Comment: большое спасибо за наводку.этот код не помог,но получилось кое что другое)джарник собрался со всеми либами. спасибо